# Should service worker script be loaded first?

Tags: service-worker

To initialize a Service Worker one has to include in thead `<head>` something like:

```
<script>
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/my-sw.js');
}
</script>
```

I found that in some example pages this isn't the first script (e.g. [flipkart.com](http://www.flipkart.com/)) of the page. Shouldn't it be the first one so that pre-caching and other features can be used ASAP? Does or doesn't the order actually matter for this script and it could well be at the bottom of the page outside `</head>`?

Answer (score 1):

`Registering a service worker will cause the browser to start the service worker install step in the background.` If successful, the `service worker` is executed in a [ServiceWorkerGlobalScope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope); this is basically a special kind of worker context, running off the main script execution thread, with no DOM access.

Being specific with your question, The order of service worker registration script doesn't matter, As an after a service worker is installed and the user navigates to a different page or refreshes, the service worker will begin to receive `fetch events`.

Comment: That's interesting. I wonder how that works when refreshing as normally if a single byte of that script changes it'll get re-installed. So how can it given that this script lives already before the page is loaded, so before it even knows if the page removed or changed the path to that `service-worker.js`.